# Get image from API Rest and print in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I have the next code to get an image from APi:

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://api.labelary.com/v1/printers/8dpmm/labels/4x6/0/",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "image/png",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": "commands ZPL",
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = response;   
    var win = window.open('');
    win.document.write(image);
    win.focus();
});
```

It was worked the api in Postman(can see the image),but in javascript not work.
[Example widnow print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmOwj.png)

Somebody help.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: When open the window of print, not showed the image...

Answer (score 1):

`win.document.write(image);` writes text (i.e. `win.document.write('<h1>Hello</h1>');` )

Instead, you want to use `document.append()` APIs to insert the node. To do that you need to find the element in the DOM to insert the node.

You can search for the body tag, or use document write to write the body tag with an ID and search for that instead.

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
 var image = new Image();
 image.src = response;   
 var win = window.open('');
 win.document.write("<html><body id='root'></body></html>");
 win.document.getElementById("root").appendChild(image);
 win.focus();
});
```

Comment: Still without working...

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Document': Only one element on document allowed.`